# SpriteKit - Run a method with two arguments after a random period of time

Tags: objective-c, methods, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

While trying to create a game for iOS I'm facing a problem: I cannot find a way to call a method that creates a SpriteKit node **from another class** that "calls itself" or repeats after a random period of time in an easy way.

The idea is this: I have a class where the scene is created. But then I have another class (subclass of SKSPriteNode) that creates the different SKSpriteNode that I need. I have one method called createObjectWithName: name position: position that takes two arguments (name and position). I need to call this method from my scene (fine until here), but I also need to repeat this method constantly in random periods of time. So, once it is called one time, it calls itself after a period of time, creating more SKSPriteNodes.

I've tried using performSelector and dispatch_after, but I hadn't had any luck so far.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the parent of these new spite nodes?

Comment: The main scene I have in a class different than the one the method to create the nodes is

Comment: Can you show us what you tried with `dispatch_after`?

Comment: @Tommy Well, the problem with dispatch_after is that I sould need to call the method that has dispatch_after and there call the other method, but since I need to pass arguments I would need to pass them twice aaaand...

Comment: @JoséMaría blocks capture state. There's no need to store it elsewhere. Also they don't require any particular factoring. The difference between calling anything now and calling it a random amount of time in the future is three lines of code, local to the caller.

Comment: How do you determine the name and position of each new sprite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, I think you want to use `SKAction` for this solution.

You could have a method for starting the spawner like this :

```
-(void)startSpawner:(float)duration range:(float)range
{

    SKAction *delay = [SKAction waitForduration:duration withRange:range];
    SKAction *spawnBlock = [SKAction runBlock:^(void)
                            {

                                NSString *spawnName = @"name";
                                CGPoint *spawnPosition = CGPointMake(someX, someY);
                                SpriteNodeSubclass *node = [SpriteNodeSubclass createObjectWithName:spawnName andPosition:spawnPosition];
                                // do something with that node if you need to.
                            }];

    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[delay, spawnBlock]];
    SKAction *repeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];
    [self runAction:repeat];
}
```

I think it's ideal to use `SKAction` as opposed to `dispatch_after`, because if you pause SpriteKit, the `SKAction` will also pause.

Comment: So, this code where should go, in the scene class or in the GameEntities class where the methods to create the items are? And then, how do I run this? Where do I call this so the items are added to the scene?

Comment: @Jose If you are unsure about how to utilize the code I posted above in your game, then it'd be best if you took a step back and took the time to learn about blocks in Objective-C, `SKAction` in SpriteKit, and fundamental Objective-C and SpriteKit programming. Not being able to utilize the above code, points to a lack of understanding in one or more of these foundational areas.

Comment: @JoséMaría This question can be likened to you wanting to fly a plane. You could get in the cockpit with a flight instructor and want to take off before you have learned about the controls and foundational concepts that need to be understood to fly a plane.

Comment: I think I understand the code above, but I'm not entirely sure how and where should I call this. I'll try to investigate a bit more about blocks, since you consider that fundamental Objective-C programming. Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, blocks are fundamental to Objective-C and understanding where this method should be called from and how is fundamental as well. How your different classes can communicate with each other and utilize their methods/properties is foundational.

Comment: So, I should call this method in the Scene, no? Then, I'm not entirely sure how to add the node to the scene...

Comment: Well, I figured it out. This has to be called in the scene. But there's something missing in your code. You need to add the node to the scene with [self addChild:[SpriteNodeSubclass createObjectWithName:spawnName andPosition:spawnPosition];

Comment: @JoséMaría What I posted has a comment that says `"// do something with that node if you need to."`  If that's adding it to the scene or another node, great.  The question was "Run a method with two arguments after a random period of time", and the code shows how to do that. The question is not about how to then implement it into your existing code, which by the way is not posted anywhere in this question.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a timestamp property in your scene class (let's call it `timeElapsedFromLastSpawn` and initialize it with 0). Then you can use this property in your update method :

```
timeElapsedFromLast += timeElapsedFromLastUpdate;
if (timeElapsedFromLast > 5.0) {
    [self spawnSpriteNode];
    timeElapsedFromLast = 0;
}
```

This will spawn a new sprite every 5 seconds. (And you can randomize it easily)

I would also recommend for the spawning method to be not in a `SKSpriteNode` instance but outside (e.g. in the parenting scene/node class) as SKSpriteNode role is to represent a sprite and not being a factory of sprites (unless it creates child sprites for it to control directly)

**EDIT:**

To calculate `timeElapsedFromLastUpdate` you can use the following code (taken from Ray Wenderlich's site which has great [tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners) about this stuff)

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
    // Handle time delta.
    // If we drop below 60fps, we still want everything to move the same distance.
    CFTimeInterval timeSinceLast = currentTime - self.lastUpdateTimeInterval;
    self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
    if (timeSinceLast > 1) { // more than a second since last update
        timeSinceLast = 1.0 / 60.0;
        self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
    }

    [self updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:timeSinceLast];

}
```

you should implement `updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate` method in your scene class or use the calculation directly in the `update` method above

Comment: +1 Looks good.  My thoughts exactly; the code should be in the scene.  Can you show the OP how to calculate `timeElapsedFromLastUpdate`?

Answer (score 0):

If this is how you call the method from your scene:

```
[otherClass createObjectWithName:name position:position];
```

Then this is how you can use GCD to schedule that call for a random amount of time later:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(
    DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 
    (int64_t)(arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)(MAX_SECONDS * NSEC_PER_SEC)))), 
    dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
^{
    [otherClass createObjectWithName:name position:position];
});
```

(assuming `MAX_SECONDS * NSEC_PER_SEC` is small enough to be represented by a 32-bit quantity; otherwise look at piling two `arc4random_uniform` calls with suitable modulo arithmetic)

So a way to that in a repeating fashion, with a `__weak` safeguard to prevent arbitrary extension of the lifetime of your object could be to use a tail call:

```
- (void)scheduleNextObject
{
    __weak YourClass *weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(
        DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 
        (int64_t)(arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)(MAX_SECONDS * NSEC_PER_SEC)))), 
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
    ^{
        // weakSelf prevents self itself from being captured, so that self
        // can be deallocated even with this loop ongoing. We'll explicitly 
        // check whether what was self still exists to stick with the idiom,
        // though it's strictly unnecessary
        YourClass *strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if(!strongSelf) return;

        [otherClass createObjectWithName:name position:position];
        [strongSelf scheduleNextObject];
    });
}
```

Comment: But how do I repeat this after a random period of time? Because I don't want it to rust just once...

Comment: @JoséMaría you're right that I'd completely missed that aspect of the question. I'll update.